# can I run a shell command in jinja2 template in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

This is a playbook that connects with all the servers in my inventory file, and makes a note of the server ip and mount point information of hosts where mount point usage exceeds 80% and it writes to a text file on the localhost (ansible-controller).

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - shell:
         cmd: df -h | sed 's/%//g' | awk '$5 > 80 {if (NR > 1) print $5"%",$6}'
      register: disk_stat
    - debug:
         var: disk_stat

    - file:
         path: /home/app/space_report_{{ td }}.txt
         state: touch
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost

    - shell: echo -e "{{ ansible_host }} '\n' {{ disk_stat.stdout_lines| to_nice_yaml }}" >> /home/thor/space_report_{{ td }}.txt
      args:
         executable: /bin/bash
      delegate_to: localhost
```

I was wondering if I could create a jinja2 template and bring the playbook down to one task. I am stuck at integrating a shell command inside the jinja2 template and I am not sure if it is possible. Please advise.

```
- hosts:  all
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: monitor.txt.j2
        dest: /home/app/playbooks/monitor.txt
      delegate_to: localhost
```

monitor.txt.j2

```
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
{{ hostvars[host].ansible_host }}
--shell command--
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: First some advice: in ansible forget your shell habits, don't use df to get space for device, and rather use ansible_facts that contains all devices and their disk usage, don't use echo either to produce a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I say in my comment under your question, while it is possible to use `shell` or `command` modules, Ansible is a configuration / automation tool, so it's better to forget your shell coding / logic to use native ansible functionalities, that'll ease the tasks / playbook writing.

For instance, it's no needed to do a `df` because ansible when connecting will gather facts about the target, including devices and their capacity and current usage so you can use that directly.

For the jinja question, you can use the module [`copy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) and pass directly jinja code in the option [`content`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html#parameter-content) on this module:

```yaml
- name: Trigger a tasks on hosts to gather facts
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    
    - copy:
         dest: /home/app/playbooks/monitor.txt
         content: |
           {% for host in groups['all'] %}
           {% for dev in hostvars[host].ansible_mounts %}
           {% if (dev.block_used / dev.block_total * 100 ) > 80 %} {{ dev.block_used / dev.block_total * 100 }} {{ dev.mount }} {% endif %}
           {% endfor %}
           {% endfor %}
       run_once: true
       delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: thank you for pointing out to right approach. I have updated my script with some custom changed inheriting the approach above. This feedback also conveys that, it is not possible to use shell command within jinja2 templates in ansible.

Comment: is it possible to augment the gather facts function to say, get the current version of a user installed application?
I want to make sure my apps are up-to-date, but installing them just to install them seems overkill, and against the idempotence idea.